# Converting xyz files with spatialite_dem

Tags: spatialite

I am trying to convert textual xyz coordinates to spatialite with [spatialite_dem](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite-tools/wiki?name=spatialite_dem#dem_importing):

```
$ spatialite_dem --srid 3346 -ddem all.db -create_dem  all.xyz 2>&1 | head -1
unknown argument: all.xyz
```

Suggestion from @user30184 doesn't work either:

```
$ spatialite_dem --srid 3346 -ddem all.sqlite -tdem test -gdem geom -create_dem  -d all.xyz
        - 'VirtualXPath'        [XML Path Language - XPath]
Segmentation fault
$
```

I compiled spatialite with debug symbols (`-g`) and found that it assumes `all.xyz` is a directory. If I replace it with `.`, it will create an empty-ish result file.

For reference, data looks as follows:

```
$ head -3 all.xyz 
500199.420,6150000.000,60.178
500214.420,6150000.000,60.158
500730.220,6150000.000,59.629
```

The help and manual pages are not helpful. How can I create a spatialite database from XYZ files using spatialite_dem?

Alternatively, I could do it manually (`CREATE TABLE points(<...>)`, `.import all.xyz points`, followed by a conversion to a geometry), but looks like `spatialite_dem` should do it out of the box.

How?

Comment: This command creates a database and table but I did not have a real xyz file and dem table does not contain any rows. Try with your data. `spatialite_dem --srid 3346 -ddem all.sqlite -tdem test -gdem geom -create_dem  -d all.xyz`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I updated the question with results from your command.

Comment: Test data would be appreciated. The not-so-brilliant document says that input can be `1. a single xyz-file 2. 
a directory of xyz-files`.

Comment: You can use a 3-row `all.xyz` of the example as the test file. It works just as well. A good test case is finding the point geometries in the resulting `.db` (or `.sqlite3`?) file.